# Директивы манифеста для расширений google chrome.

Tags: google-chrome

Хотелось бы узнать, какие директивы существуют в манифесте для google chrome расширений. Желательно ссылку на полный список, сколько в интернете не искал, ничего так и не нашёл.

В частности интересует такая вот директива:

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["http://example.com"]
  }
```

Не могу понять как это работает, там еще какие-то звездочки используются(*)?

Comment: первое что выдает google: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest  и там есть этот параметр

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72050/discussion-on-question-by-shillkas-----google-chr).